# SQLite round midpoint

Tags: sqlite, sqlite-net

I'm trying to use the SQLite function ROUND like this:

```
select ROUND(1.655, 2)
```

The result is 1.65, but i need this to round up to 1.66, like on c#

```
Math.Round(1.655, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: No. SQLite doesn't have a built in feature for that

Comment: according to this http://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/functions/round.php that is suppose to work, try typing `round` with small letters, maybe it's case sensitive

Comment: I don't think its case sensitive, i've tried and the result is the same. The problem here is with the mid point round, that round down and not up.

Comment: The [official documentation for the `round` function](http://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#round) doesn't specify a direction. You may want to [create your own SQL function](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html) that does what you want (if sqlite-net exposes this functionality).

Comment: @LuthandoNtsekwa it's unclear what the link you posted should explain. I don't see any specification about rounding away from zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i've been trying to use the Colonel Thirty Two tip, of using the [Binding functions](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html), but sqlite-net doesn't provide such functionality.
I've turn to the System.Data.SQLite.dll, so to help others:

First create a custom function in c#

```
[SQLiteFunction(Name = "RoundAccounting", Arguments = 2, FuncType = FunctionType.Scalar)]
public class RoundAccounting : SQLiteFunction
{
    public override object Invoke(object[] args)
    {
        decimal value = 0;
        int decimalPlaces = 0;

        if(decimal.TryParse(args[0].ToString(), out value) && int.TryParse(args[1].ToString(), out decimalPlaces))
            return Math.Round(value, decimalPlaces, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);

        return 0;
    }
}
```

then on the data layer we bind the function to the connection created:

```
using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(string.Format("Data Source={0}", dbPath)))
        {
            var function = new RoundAccounting();
            var attributes = function.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SQLiteFunctionAttribute), true).Cast<SQLiteFunctionAttribute>().ToArray();
            await connection.OpenAsync();
            connection.BindFunction(attributes[0], function);

            SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT RoundAccounting(somecolumn, 2);", connection); .....
```